# Python- why sklearn Imputer deal with columns without missing values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am preprocessing this data set http://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-big-mart-sales-iii which has categorical and numerical variables at the same time.
I use sklearn's Imputer to impute missing values. I have confirmed there are only two columns (Item_Weight and Outlet_Size) have missing values.I haven't convert categorical variables to numerical ones in my data.
Currently I use

```
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)
```

to deal with missing values, and when I run `imp.fit(mydata)`, there is an error message: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Supermarket Type1`
But the 'Supermarket Type1' is a value in "outlet_type" column which turns out not a column with missing values.
So why Imputer deal with columns without missing values? I thought it only deals with columns with missing values.

Comment: In order to find a good fit for the missing value, it is most probably checking other column's values. I don't know which algorithm sklearn uses for imputation but good imputers generally does that.

Comment: Thanks ayhan. If there is a strategy of "nearest neighbor" to impute missing value, I believe the algorithm must check all columns' value, but for Imputer the strategy only includes mean, median and most_frequent. Anyway it is another way to think of issues.